# How to insert elements in a vector at regular intervals in R

Tags: r

Is there any alternative method of R for the problem explained here: [How to insert elements in a vector at regular intervals in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845713/how-to-insert-elements-in-a-vector-at-regular-intervals-in-matlab)

Namely, from a vector `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)`, I want to obtain a vector `y` given by

```
y     <- c(0, 1, 2, 3,
           0, 4, 5, 6,
           0, 7, 8, 9,
           0,10,11,12)
```

... I found the following page,... maybe duplicate

[R: insert elements into vector (a variation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606157/r-insert-elements-into-vector-a-variation)

---

**Edit**  I slighly modified the answer of @jay.sf . I think his `interval.length` is not our intuitive interval length.

```
    x <- 1:16
    interval.length <- 2
    co_interval.length <- length(x)/interval.length
    as.vector(t(cbind(0, matrix(x, co_interval.length, byrow=T))))

[1]  0  1  2  0  3  4  0  5  6  0  7  8  0  9 10  0 11 12  0 13 14  0 15 16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a matrix and coerce it into a vector.

```
interval.length <- 4
as.vector(t(cbind(0, matrix(x, interval.length, byrow=T))))
# [1]  0  1  2  3  0  4  5  6  0  7  8  9  0 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to make use of arithmetical indexing:

```r
y <- numeric(16)
y[x + 1 + (x - 1) %/% 3] <- x
y
#> [1]  0  1  2  3  0  4  5  6  0  7  8  9  0 10 11 12
```